# SML How to subtract 2 lists and compare the product?

Tags: sml

I'm trying to subtract 2 lists and return the compared product.

So if list
a   = [2,3,2]
b   = [1,1,1] 
then 
a-b = [1,2,1] and the returned product (c) should be 1.

```
val c = List.map (fn i => (i - b) mod 10) a
```

modulo (mod) 10 is for cases where the two subtracted numbers gives an odd result, e.g. 2-8 = ~6 mod 10 = 4.

I'm stuck at the subtraction, because List.map doesn't allow me to do the subtraction because it expects an int value and not an int list (at least not the way I have coded it :(  ).

I'm also blank on the comparison.

Comment: What do you mean by the compared product?

Comment: I should have express it differently, what I meant was the most frequent value in the c list and return just that.

Comment: I want to compared the c list with itself, to check if all the elements are the same value, and if the are then return that value. A bonus would be to additionally check if they aren't, then which value that is the most frequently represented + figuring out which elements that doesn't fit in and return their value and location.

Comment: I came up with this "val n_filter = List.all (fn x => x = n_value_char) n_chars" to solve the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ListPair.map` to iterate over 2 lists at once, like this:

```
val c = ListPair.map (fn (i, j) => (i - j) mod 10) (a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to subtract `b` — you want to subtract *the corresponding value*. A convenient way to do this is to zip the lists together:

```
val c = List.map (fn (i, j) => (i - j) mod 10) (ListPair.zip (a, b))
```